# containing div inheriting the width of inner list that has absolute position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to find a way to have a containing div adjust to the width of a list that has a position of absolute. Is this even possible? I am trying to do it with pure css.

```
<div class="list">
    <span id="nav">menu</span>
    <ol class="select">
        <li data-value="en">some text here</li>
       <li data-value="de">some text here</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div>
text here
</div>
```

I basically want this to preform like a select list in a form where the containing div adjusts to the width of the OL and lays over the text below when the dropdown occurs. code is here http://jsfiddle.net/rBXRT/168/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this works with CSS, but with jQuery you can simply add the following line:

```
$(".list").css({width: $(".select").outerWidth()});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rBXRT/169/

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I might just have to go with that.

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/64qQL/)***

Absolutely positioned elements will be removed from the flow of the page and will be relative to the next containing element with position. Since none are marked as such for you, that is the document body.

Marking the div .list with `position:relative` will cause that element to be the parent element with position and thus force the child elements to be contained to that width.

```
.list{
 background:red;
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
}
```